# VBA Making range also include inserted rows

Tags: vba

I am using the following code to update the date if someone changes some text. The problem is if I want to insert more rows, as I have defined my range as "D9:D16".

Is there way to make it so that this code is observant of new rows being inserted?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Hvis du på noget tidspunkt tilføjer flere rows, så sig til.
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Intersect(Range("D9:D16"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(, -2).Formula = "=UDF_Now()"
        Select Case MsgBox("Er ""Updated by"" den rigtige?", vbYesNo)
        Case Is = vbNo
            Target.Offset(, -1).Activate
        End Select
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You could created a named range instead and refer to that in your code, or use a proper table

Answer (score 0):

`Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row` can be used to find the last used row, so once u insert a new row, the result is incremented by one.

So try something like :

`If Not Intersect(Range("D9:D" & Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row), Target) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: It's working, but the issue is that I have other stuff going on down below the area that I want this VBA to format, leading to my user defined function being inserted into cells they're not supposed to.